# Juju Bootstrap Error

Tags: juju

I have installed MAAS, juju. When try to setup juju to work on MASS with running juju bootstrap on command line, juju complaining regarding the storage that it need of the nodes. Yet on the nodes list the two nodes i have already commissioned and on ready state.
But i notice that both my storage and disk are both zero while CPU and RAM info looks normal to me.
So i jump to this note 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot and it stuck on the same step above when the installer try to run juju bootstrap .. Error message contain lines below ................
No storage information. Commissioning this node will gather the storage information. ....................
Could someone help ..... thanks in advance

Comment: anyone can help please !!!

Comment: Can you confirm that storage devices are enlisted in your MAAS node configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I found that re-commissioning the nodes resolved this issue for me. (select commission in the UI, and OK, then power cycle the node(s) if necessary to proceed with commissioning)